# Single Sign On For OpenStack and My Web App

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, single-sign-on, openstack

I have been trying to achieve **Single Sign On for OpenStack and a Web app** (ASP.NET business app to be specific). I want to allow access to OpenStack cloud from my Web app (assume **Web app user is also an OpenStack user**) i.e., I don't want the user to enter his credentials again for cloud access. I thought Single Sign On would work. Does it need any changes on the OpenStack (Keystone) side. Please help me get started with this.

Thanks,
Shaileshwar

Answer (score 0):

In openstack kilo release they introduced the sso (single sign on)..just gothrough